# how to move an UIImage based on co ordinates given

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

i wanted to know if there is a way where an UIImage moves based on multiple co ordinates given in the program  for ex : one co ordinates will be to move like 10 pixels frm left to right 
2nd co ordinates will be to continue from rprevious co ordinates and move 20 pixels frm top to bottom and so on

Comment: can you post some examples? your question is not very clear..

Comment: change the x,y position of your image view.

Comment: for example imagine there is a movie playing in a background UIView and there is an man walking from left to right and dancing . i want to put the image on top of man's face , based on his face movements the image has to shift directions accordingly

Comment: **bold** 2nd co ordinates should continue from where the last co ordinates ended and move 20 pixels frm top to bottom and so on **bold**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**you can make an action like below**

```
- (IBAction) doMoveLeft : (UIImageView *) sender
{
    yourImageView=sender; //Make yourImageView globally accessible.
    [yourImageView setFrame:(X,Y,Width,Height)];
}

/*
> Increase or Decrease your X,Y as per the requirement. Make (X,Y) of int type. 
And Put them at global to access it where you need!

> At the time of showing images on your view, you can also give them dynamic 
tags to distinguish them for further use.
*/
```